# Heroku: gunicorn and waitress-serve commands not working

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, gunicorn, waitress

I'm building a website which I want to deploy to Heroku. I used an empty django project, configured the static root and tried to deploy it.

When I deploy it, This is what Heroku shows me this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p68jA.png)

Here is what the console showed:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qeh7a.png)

I found out that gunicorn was not a function even though I had installed it, as the Heroku bash said that the command was not found. I also tried using waitress, but the issue persisted. I also tried using `python`. I use a Windows 10 PC and I used the Heroku CLI to deploy the Django application. I have gunicorn and waitress in my requirements.txt and I have tried installing and running gunicorn in the heroku console using `pip install gunicorn  && gunicorn mysite.wsgi`.

I want to know how I can get the server running.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Here are the contents of my `requirements.txt`:

```
appdirs==1.4.4
asgiref==3.3.1
certifi==2020.12.5
distlib==0.3.1
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.1.6
filelock==3.0.12
gunicorn==20.0.4
pipenv==2020.11.15
psycopg2==2.8.6
pytz==2021.1
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
virtualenv==20.4.2
virtualenv-clone==0.5.4
waitress==1.4.4
whitenoise==5.2.0
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: And please include _all_ relevant log messages. You won't be able to `pip install` things on Heroku. Are you entirely sure that you have included these libraries in your `requirements.txt`? Do you see them get installed during deployment?

Comment: In the first time I tried to deploy, I did see all the modules getting installed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your `requirements.txt`. Do you also have `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` files?